# How to take output from .NET executable and convey to MFC application?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, mfc

I have a dialog based MFC application through which I have to call a .NET executable.

My question are:

1. How will the MFC application know that the .NET executable is closed?
2. if suppose a .Net executable process some information and want to convey the output to the MFC application, how can this be achieved.

Please help!!

Comment: What is the "output" of the .NET application? Is that a command line application writing to standard output?

Comment: No it is a winform application. Let's suppose it queries database for a particular search critaria and outputs the result.

Comment: I am just to ask how the exe convey the output.. yes it can be flat file...but what is the best way ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MFC application can just wait for the .NET process to exit in the normal way - either using a wait handle or by polling it.

As for collecting output - the simplest mechanisms is likely to be for the .NET executable to write to a file, and then the MFC app can read it afterwards. It's crude but very easy to implement!

Answer (score 1):

1) Your MFC application can use CreateProcess() to run the .NET EXE and then use the [GetExitCodeProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189(VS.85).aspx) function to find out if it has finished. If it hasn't finished, this API returns STILL_ACTIVE(259).

2) If the .NET EXE outputs to the command line, you can read the output using the Standard Handle StdOut and StdErr. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683231(VS.85).aspx).

Alternatively, invoke your .NET EXE via the Command Line like this:

> ShellExecute("%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\Cmd.exe
>   /C \"Path to your .NET EXE\" >
>   %TEMP%\CaptureOutput.txt", ...)

and then wait on the 'CaptureOutput.txt' file and read its' contents.

Comment: I am new to MFC can you please give me the syntax of CreateProcess ?? and GetExitProcess ??

Comment: Here is the documentation for CreateProcess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx You can Google/Bing for examples.